# Intentionally de-laminating bent bed slats

Tags: veneer, laminating, steam-bending

I'm trying to intentionally de-laminate bent bed slats - think [Luroy Ikea Slats](https://www.ikea.com/cz/en/p/luroey-slatted-bed-base-90160211/) - I want to get the individual veneer strips out of these so that I can re-bend (probably steam) and glue together into different shapes.
The wood is pretty hard (I think it is birch). I believe these are glued together, but I don't know what type glue is used.

What I have tried so far:

- soaking it in water (up to 24 hours most - should I try longer?)
- steaming them (although only with a handheld clothes steamer)

All I was able to get was one strip out of one slat while destroying the rest of it.

I'm looking for advice on how to de-laminate these intentionally so that I get the most of the wood out in strips.

- Any chemicals I should try?
- Should I leave it soaking in water for longer than 24 hours?
- Should I steam it extensively in a steam box (which I don't have yet)?
- Anything else?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking! You likely won't be able to do this, possibly at all but if it is possible then I'm very doubtful this would be economically viable *unless* you already had everything that is (possibly) necessary. IF there is a method that could do this efficiently and with minimal losses what if it costs 3000 Kč? So instead, wouldn't it be better to approach this the conventional way by starting with the raw materials?

Comment: Also in terms of the Question, you're asking a little too much. There are five question marks here. Although everything is intrinsically related of course in order to Answer the Question as asked (as we're instructed to do) someone would have to address every one of those. When really what you're asking can be boiled down to, *"Is there a viable method for separating the laminations from XX material?"* (Which is unanswerable with the information we currently have.)

Comment: Not sure what you're after here, but it may well just be easier and more cost effective to buy/cut your own birch veneer to laminate it yourself.

Comment: I think the chances of destroying the wood is better than separating the laminated layers.

Comment: Hi all, Thank you for the comments. @Graphus the reason I wanted to do it with the slats is that I already have a bunch and wanted to upcycle. The conventional approach is probably better. And I'll make my future questions more clear and concise.

Comment: @FreeMan I guess you are right. The thing is that I already have the slats (that I picked up for free), so there is a spirit of upcycling in this. But if I really want to do the project that I had in mind, it would make the most sense to buy raw materials and laminate myself. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes, re/up-cycling takes more time, effort & energy than using new. Use the slats for something that can use them as-is.

Comment: What @FreeMan, just said is exactly what I was going to. If you have the storage space it's well worth holding on to this material until you can find a use for it as-is. I've kept the laminated 'feet' from a couple of recliners (also birch I think) with no particular plan how I was going to use it, just didn't want it to go to waste. So far the material has yielded a pair of vice linings and a couple of star knobs, and I hope to make an oilstone box from the biggest pieces.